# JSLint reports Insecure '^' in my regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have use regex
`tableString.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g, "");`

for repalacing  tag from my html string. How can I get rid of this problem?Please suggest another valid regular expression.

Comment: Err, how is that insecure?

Comment: This is done. Even JSLint knows parsing HTML with regex is dangerous and insecure.

Comment: Solution: don't listen to JSLint.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that regex. Ignore the warning.

Comment: "Don't listen to JSLint" is never the answer. Always investigate to learn where JSLint is coming from and then carefully decide which warnings don't apply in your circumstance on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: If you know what you're doing you can select "Tolerate . and [^...] in /RegExp/"

Comment: @Quentin I was talking for this case only. It's always a good idea to understand the *why*, but this warning is braindead.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I guess we shall see who will become braindead once Tony the pony finds out somebody's trying to process HTML with regular expressions.

Comment: @Ja͢ck yeah, that's a different matter.